# Python Pandas DateOffset using value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I was thinking this would be very easy but the below is not working for what I want. Just trying to compute a new date column by adding days to a pre-existing datetime column using values from another column. My 'offset' column below just has 1 digit numbers.

```
df['new_date'] = df['orig_date'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(days=df['offset']))
```

Error: `unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series`

thank you,

Answer (score 10):

```
In [12]: df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'].apply(pd.offsets.Day)

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
           A  B          C
0 2013-01-01  0 2013-01-01
1 2013-01-02  1 2013-01-03
2 2013-01-03  2 2013-01-05
3 2013-01-04  3 2013-01-07
4 2013-01-05  4 2013-01-09
```

Comment: really appreciate it.

Comment: Good solution, but it is not vectorised :D!

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, but it may be useful for others with the same doubt. There is a way of doing this in a **vectorised way**, so it is much faster.

```
df['new_date'] = df['orig_date'] + df['offset'].astype('timedelta64[D]'))
```

Comment: This is excellent man. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note, that it will have absolute time arithmetic vs calendar arithmetic that's used by DateOffset. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32026