# Using pandas dateoffset and step forward num_years (given by a column)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a dataframe with column of datetime "Date_Begin".  I have another column "Years_to_add".  I want to calculate a third column with the "DateBegin" stepped forward by the number of years in the "years_to_add" column.  I want to avoid using approximations like 365.25 in a year.  I want simply add the number of years in a calendar sense (I know there will be problems with adding a year to 29 Feb).

In my version of pandas I can't use years as timedelta (no longer supported), so I am using the DateOffset method.

I can't get the syntax right.  I have tried the following, based on suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917144/python-pandas-dateoffset-using-value-from-another-column):

```
df["begin_date"] + pd.DateOffset(years=int(df["years_to_add"]))

df["begin_date"] + df["years_to_add"].apply(pd.DateOffset.years)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it as lambda function

```
df["begin_date"] + df["years_to_add"].apply(lambda y: pd.DateOffset(years=y))
```

Comment: Sorry for delay.  The solution works but it gives me a warning error: `PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to DatetimeArray not vectorized`.  Is there a better way to use the DateOffset function to avoid this?

Comment: Addition on `DateOffset` to `DatetimeArray` itself is not vectorized since there is no low level dtype for `DateOffset`. There is a dtype for `timedelta` it allows only offsets sepecified in days doesn't support years. So there is no better way to use `DateOffset` to vectorize. @Tim